# Implementing MassTransit CorrelatedBy<Guid> interface without MassTransit nuget

Tags: nuget, correlation, masstransit

Building my first Saga state machine implementation. 
I've written an interfaces nuget package to share Saga events and commands between the services acting on and publishing these events. I implement Masstransit CorrelatedBy< Guid> for each event/command via base class.

```
public class BaseSagaEvent : CorrelatedBy<Guid>, IBaseSagaEvent
    {
        public Guid CorrelationId { get; set; }

        ...
    }
```

I like keeping interface nugets (Nugets that are basically just interfaces and poco classes), light, without nuget dependencies (just my experience with nuget hell ).
Is there a way to implement CorrelatedBy without adding the entire Masstransit nuget to the interface project, while still enjoy the StateMachine correlation?

Comment: How are you using MassTransit without NuGet dependencies? 

Answer (score 0):

The only way to automatically correlate a message to a state machine saga is to use the `CorrelatedBy<Guid>` interface. The current code has no way to automatically determine the correlation identifier by name, type, or otherwise.

Events without the interface must be declared using the syntax shown (same as the documentation).

```
Event(() => SomeSagaEvent, x => x.CorrelatedById(m => m.Message.Id))
```

Comment: So your answer is no. If I want to implement CorrelatedBy<Guid> I must add masstransit nuget to my events nuget (or forget about implementing CorrelatedBy<Guid>)

Comment: @orenshochat it seems like you're actually asking them to create a separate nuget package with just the interfaces? Like other parties (like Microsoft) are also doing (eg https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions/).

Comment: A [recent commit](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/commit/454840bcfda4a316c154c0e039c4062099837d08) that will be released with v7 supports discovery a a Guid property named CorrelationId, CommandId, or EventId, and also supports configuring the correlationId by message type which will be used by Automatonymous to correlate the state machine.